# Can we suppress the Main report records, If the Subreport returns No Data in Crystal report?

Tags: crystal-reports, logic, crystal-reports-xi

I am Using Remedy AR ODBC DataSource, where We can not use Joins, as AR ODBC does not support join, So I am Using SubReport in Detail section(Used Proper Link)
when I am running the Report:

i.e., Main Report has 3000 Records and Maching Records in SubReport has 1000 records
when I am running the Report, It shows all 3000Records and Blank Subreport where Data Does Not match(against 2000 Records),

Is there a way I can get only 1000 Records (Matching Records) in Report.
(Need to implement innerjoin)

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a shared variable to count the number of records processed in the subreports. On the main report, if that variable is zero you can conditionally suppress that details section from displaying. It certainly won't speed things up, but it will prevent those records from displaying.